# Generic parameter 'Arg' could not be inferred - generic memoization function

Tags: swift

I'm trying to build a generic memoization function

```
func memoize<Arg: Hashable, Ret>(_ fn: @escaping ((Arg) -> Ret)) -> ((Arg) -> Ret) {
    var cache: [Arg:Ret] = [:]
    func inner (x: Arg) -> Ret {
        let ret = cache[x, default: fn(x)]
        cache[x] = ret
        return ret
    }
    return inner
}
```

But I am unable to define my function as a closure for some reason

```
struct Foo: Hashable {
    let a: String
    let b: String
}


let foo = memoize(
    (x: Foo) -> String in {
        print("miss")
        return x.a
    }
)
```

```
Cannot convert value of type '((Foo) -> String).Type' to expected argument type '(Arg) -> Ret'

Generic parameter 'Arg' could not be inferred
```

why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your closure syntax is incorrect. The signature part goes *inside* of the `{ }` (See [Closure Expression Syntax](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID97)):

```
let foo = memoize(
    { (x: Foo) -> String in
        print("miss")
        return x.a
    }
)
```

You can also omit the `()` (known as a [trailing closure](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID102)), which is more idiomatic:

```
let foo = memoize { 
    (x: Foo) -> String in
    print("miss")
    return x.a
}
```

Comment: thanks learning swift - finding the closure syntax a bit tricky